# How to add Bootstrap Class like col-md-4 to your fields

Tags: theming

[image]

This is my form and i want to make all the select tabs in one line
How and where i will write bootstrap class to make this all select box come in one row.

Comment: Please provide more details about the form?

Comment: Consider looking into this one: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/234195/62859

Comment: Use hook_form_BASE_ID_alter() to get the form, then add #prefix having opening tags to the starting form select and add #suffix having closing, opening tags to rest form selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module named field group. Download that module and then extend that. In Content type field edit form there a button will come with name of add group. Select HTML element and fill the required details and just arrange that in manage form display. U can add any css class. Then save that. Hope that will help